# howto get a JSON (or equivalent) representation of a JavaScript *code file* (the code, as a string, in input)?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, serialization, representation

Everything is in the title! ^^

I know about some SourceCode browsers for js; they usually permit to find some small stuff when the code relatively abides in structure by the current informal js coding norm.

*(eg, use of the `new` operator, functions mainly created through definitions (`F foo() {}`) rather than through expression statements or literal objects (`var foo = F(){}`, `{ foo: F(){} }`), etc; norm i precisely happen not to do adhere to).*

but, what would truly interest me would be a full parsing of the code, a tool returning, for example, a JSON file containing the whole code, that is, all the statements, function calls, even the parameters of the function calls (usually forgotten in js sourcebrowsers, because those objects are de facto anonymous objects/functions; however they are precisely abundantly used in functional-like programming, and thus get invisible to all source browsers i met)

the purpose of course would be to create from that JSONized code, my own source browser, that would hopefully go farther than the average one, and would meet my needs to browse my code easily, see also easily, which variable is defined where, and some other stuff that might enhance my coding experience.

anyhow; i'm not particularly attached to the JSON format, altho of course since i'd code my source browser in JS, it'd be the immediate easy input, but any other data representation format is OK, what matters is a parser that transforms code into a mouthpiece object¹.
Anything looking and doing sth like that (eg a L/Hinter with a more verbose and informative output, or else) is welcome ;)

thanks in advance :)

*¹ "object": an object as JS defines it, ie, an abstract data alike or identical to a dictionary; not an object as class-based OO languages define it (class instances)*

Comment: sorry, cant figure out the sense, you mean like JSON.stringify?, is very easy to transform js objects into json, catn get your question

Comment: i'm searching for a tool (preferably JS-written, but it's not a requisite) that would take as input, a js source file (as a string, for example typically `"(function () { ... return MyLib })()"`) and would return an object representing that code file, for example, describing the function calls, the entered parameters, the statement structures (loops, etc), etc, in short, everything in the code, represented in a readable way (for a js source browser of course).

, , , , Is it clearer? don't hesitate to re-ask if i still haven't managed to explain my problem clearly ^^ ;)

Comment: I dont think what you are asking makes sense, how would you represent a foreach in json? and an injected service?

Comment: for the injected service, i don't know what it means. for a forEach, i can imagine i'd be an array representing a list of calls: #1 entry is the array, #2 is the forEach call, with inner entries as such: type=function call, name="forEach", parameters = [anonymous function]. then this representation of an anonymous function would itself contain one property for the arguments' names, one other for the body of the function, itself an array of statements. it's of course recursive in structure, but do you see where i'm going?

Comment: it's not about creating a runnable code from a json object, it's about *representing*, *describing* a source code in JSON, the final purpose being the exploration of that representation in a dynamic way, exactly like any source code browser. it's not like an HTML file: it represents a webpage (for example), it does is only a descriptor of a real suitable webpage; but the main difference is that here i don't want a represented js file for generating that js file, i only want to display a code browser of de facto already written code files.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are searching for a standard to represent javascript code as an abstract syntax tree (AST). There is a widely used standard for javascript AST and it is called [ESTree](https://github.com/estree/estree). There is an active community supporting the standardization project and it is updated for new versions of javascript.

Alternatively, there is also [Shift AST](http://shift-ast.org/) that offers a slightly different standard AST, and it has an online real time parsing tool.

Implementations of AST generators usually provide a `Parser` with a `parse()` method that take your javascript code as a string parameter value, and they return an abstract syntax tree object as defined by the standard.

For example passing this code:

```
c = a + b;
```

Will produce this AST:

```
type: "Script"
directives:[]
statements:
    0:
        type: "ExpressionStatement"
        expression:
            type: "AssignmentExpression"
            binding:
                type: "BindingIdentifier"
                name: "c"
            expression:
                type: "BinaryExpression"
                left:
                    type: "IdentifierExpression"
                    name: "a"
                operator: "+"
                right:
                    type: "IdentifierExpression"
                    name: "b"
```

Finally, there are code generators to perform the reverse procedure: when having an AST and wanting to generate javascript code from that.

An updated and well maintained implementation of an ESTree parser can be found [here](https://github.com/ternjs/acorn).